# ES6 + Uglifier with Jekyll: Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: keyword (const)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, uglifier

Here is the complete error:

```
Liquid Exception: Unexpected token: keyword (const). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true). in /_layouts/base.html
```

I found online that the solution should be to use:

```
Uglifier.compile(js, harmony: true)
```

in a `production.rb` file, which I don't have since I'm using Jekyll and all I can set is in `config.yml`:

```
...
assets:
  js_compressor: uglifier
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your `_config.yml`: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/502#issuecomment-365955221

```
  assets:
    ...
    external:
      uglifier:
        harmony: true
```

Answer (score -2):

Get rid of Uglifier. It doesn't support ES6, or at least it doesn't with the configuration that ships with Rails.

Comment: I mean, my site went from "not building or starting" to "building and starting and running just fine", so it seems like a solution to me.

Comment: Maybe I'll want to add Javascript minification/obfuscation back into the project, as an optimization, when I'm almost ready to ship. But for now, it's a premature optimization that was breaking my site, and apparently yours.